# Pandas: How to delete rows that do not match certain condition with a counter?

Tags: python, pandas

With a dataset that looks roughly like this:

```
index_right = pd.Series([8620, 8620, 8620, 8650, 8650, 8650, 133000, 133000, 133000])
index_left = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
month_index = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
time_index = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])


dict1 = {'index_right': index_right, 'index_left': index_left, 'month_index': month_index, 'time_index': time_index}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df
```

```
    index_right index_left  month_index time_index
    8620        0.0         1.0             1.0
    8620        0.0         1.0             2.0
    8620        0.0         1.0             3.0
    8650        1.0         2.0             1.0
    8650        1.0         2.0             2.0
    8650        1.0         2.0             3.0
    133000      NaN         NaN             1.0
    133000      NaN         NaN             2.0
    133000      NaN         NaN             3.0
```

I would like to go through each `index_left` and delete any row that does not match on `month_index` and `time_index`.

The result should look something like this:

```
    index_right index_left  month_index time_index
    8620            0.0         1.0         1.0
    8650            1.0         2.0         2.0
    133000      NaN         NaN         1.0
    133000      NaN         NaN         2.0
    133000      NaN         NaN         3.0
```

My approach was to for loop over and delete the index location in place, but I am struggling with it (currently not working):

```
for i in range(test_case.shape[0]):
    if test_case.iloc[i]['month_index'] != test_case.iloc[i]['time_index']:
        test_case.drop(test_case.index[i], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to check if the Series are equals:

```
res = df[df['month_index'].eq(df['time_index'])]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   index_left  month_index  time_index
0           0            1           1
4           1            2           2
```

Also works to do:

```
res = df[df['month_index'] == df['time_index']]
```

**UPDATE**

For the new example you need to check also the values that are *NAN*:

```
res = df[(df['month_index'] == df['time_index']) | (df['month_index'].isna() & df['month_index'].isna())]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   index_right  index_left  month_index  time_index
0         8620         0.0          1.0           1
4         8650         1.0          2.0           2
6       133000         NaN          NaN           1
7       133000         NaN          NaN           2
8       133000         NaN          NaN           3
```

Comment: I will fix my question, this does work. I am actually trying to delete rows that do not meet the condition. The reason, I have a long time series structure that I want to maintain. So in joining the two datasets with a left join, I have extra data mapped to each row that needs to get deleted.

Comment: @JohnStud What is the output?

Comment: Updated the examples to keep the rows that are still useful

Comment: @JohnStud Updated the answer!

Comment: Brilliant, the OR makes sense.